# In FBX, how do you know which vert indexes correspond to which control point indexes?

Tags: c++, directx-11, fbx

I am currently trying to load an FBX mesh for use with DirectX, but my FBX file has it's UVs stored by vert index and the normals stored by control point index. How do I know which vertexes have which control point's values?

My code for loading positions, uvs and normals is ripped straight from the fbx example code, but I can post it if needed.

edit: as requested, here are the parts of my code I am talking about.

The UV code will go into the if statement for mapping mode by vert index, while the normal code is set to mapping mode by ctrl point

```
//load uvs
if (lUVElement->GetMappingMode() == FbxGeometryElement::eByControlPoint)
                {
                    for (int lPolyIndex = 0; lPolyIndex < lPolyCount; ++lPolyIndex)
                    {
                        // build the max index array that we need to pass into MakePoly
                        const int lPolySize = mesh->GetPolygonSize(lPolyIndex);
                        for (int lVertIndex = 0; lVertIndex < lPolySize; ++lVertIndex)
                        {

                            //get the index of the current vertex in control points array
                            int lPolyVertIndex = mesh->GetPolygonVertex(lPolyIndex, lVertIndex);

                            //the UV index depends on the reference mode
                            int lUVIndex = lUseIndex ? lUVElement->GetIndexArray().GetAt(lPolyVertIndex) : lPolyVertIndex;

                            lUVValue = lUVElement->GetDirectArray().GetAt(lUVIndex);

                            _floatVec->push_back((float)lUVValue.mData[0]);
                            _floatVec->push_back((float)lUVValue.mData[1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (lUVElement->GetMappingMode() == FbxGeometryElement::eByPolygonVertex)
                {
                    int lPolyIndexCounter = 0;
                    for (int lPolyIndex = 0; lPolyIndex < lPolyCount; ++lPolyIndex)
                    {
                        // build the max index array that we need to pass into MakePoly
                        const int lPolySize = mesh->GetPolygonSize(lPolyIndex);
                        for (int lVertIndex = 0; lVertIndex < lPolySize; ++lVertIndex)
                        {
                            if (lPolyIndexCounter < lIndexCount)
                            {

                                //the UV index depends on the reference mode
                                int lUVIndex = lUseIndex ? lUVElement->GetIndexArray().GetAt(lPolyIndexCounter) : lPolyIndexCounter;

                                lUVValue = lUVElement->GetDirectArray().GetAt(lUVIndex);

                                _floatVec->push_back((float)lUVValue.mData[0]);
                                _floatVec->push_back((float)lUVValue.mData[1]);

                                lPolyIndexCounter++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

//and now normals
if (lNormalElement->GetMappingMode() == FbxGeometryElement::eByControlPoint)
                {
                    //Let's get normals of each vertex, since the mapping mode of normal element is by control point
                    for (int lVertexIndex = 0; lVertexIndex < mesh->GetControlPointsCount(); lVertexIndex++)
                    {
                        int test = mesh->GetControlPointsCount();
                        int lNormalIndex = 0;
                        //reference mode is direct, the normal index is same as vertex index.
                        //get normals by the index of control vertex
                        if (lNormalElement->GetReferenceMode() == FbxGeometryElement::eDirect)
                            lNormalIndex = lVertexIndex;

                        //reference mode is index-to-direct, get normals by the index-to-direct
                        if (lNormalElement->GetReferenceMode() == FbxGeometryElement::eIndexToDirect)
                            lNormalIndex = lNormalElement->GetIndexArray().GetAt(lVertexIndex);

                        //Got normals of each vertex.
                        FbxVector4 lNormal = lNormalElement->GetDirectArray().GetAt(lNormalIndex);

                        _floatVec->push_back((float)lNormal[0]);
                        _floatVec->push_back((float)lNormal[1]);
                        _floatVec->push_back((float)lNormal[2]);

                    }
                }
                else if (lNormalElement->GetMappingMode() == FbxGeometryElement::eByPolygonVertex)
                {

                            //etc... code wont go here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

So how can I know which vertexes will have which normals?

Comment: "but I can post it if needed." : please do so buddy - by editing your question.

Comment: If you have fbx sdk, there is a sample named ImportScene, the DisplayMesh.cxx will show you how to retrieve mesh info.